# how can i remove ability to click of fullcalendar events while page loads

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

My code snippet

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      allDaySlot: false,
      header: {
        left: 'today prev next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
      timeFormat: {agenda: 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm}'},
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      editable: false,
      minTime: '8:30am',
      maxTime: '10:00pm',
      weekends: false,
      eventRender: function(event, element) {
        // some code
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          //some code
      },
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, calEvent) {
          //some code
        }
```

Further there are ajax calls to refresh the calendar and display events.
i would like to disable click of the calendar events while page loads i.e, while the ajax requests are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

set a variable in the global scope, calling it for example `preventAjax` with a value of false. Set it to `true` before firing the request and back to `false` when the request is successful. Execute the ajax request only when the value is false. For example

```
var preventAjax = false;

function someFunction() {
   if (preventAjax)
       return;

   preventAjax = true;
   $.ajax({
     url : "someUrl",
     success : function(data) {
        preventAjax = false;

        // ... other code ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I do not want to stop the ajax request. The click on fullcalendar events (day click or event click) needs to be prevented while ajax loading.

Comment: Its the same approach, set a global var while doing an ajax request, release on success. Return from fullcalendar events dayClick, eventClick when said var is set to true.

Comment: You can use ajaxStart and ajaxSuccess methods to catch the ajax events